# asp dropdown selectedvalue = "" when populating with javascript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

How do I use asp:dropdown in a webform with no options until they are populated by javascript via an api in the browser?

I have successfully used jquery to populate the fields but once I submit the form, `selectedValue` equals `""` every time.

The reason I'm using asp:dropdownlist is because for the edit form I'm prepopulating the fields with the API values but after I change them in the front end `selectedvalue` doesn't represent the correct value. if i don't load any values `selectedvalue` is always `""`

I have 3 dropdown lists that are "linked"

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="first"  class="form-control first" runat="server" />
<asp:dropdownlist id="second"  class="form-control second" runat="server" />
<asp:dropdownlist id="third"  class="form-control third" runat="server" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    populateFirst();
    $('.first').change(function () {
         populateSecond();
    });
   // etc...
)};
```

in the submit handler, regardless of what I select:

```
dim firstVal = first.selectedvalue ' equals "" 
dim secondVal = second.selectedvalue ' equals ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a client side ddl will not have any view state.

So, if you want the index of the selection?

Then you want to save/get and use a control to persist that value upon post-back.

This example shows a proof of concept:
(i used jQuery)

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="post back"
            OnClick="Button2_Click" CssClass="btn"
            />            
        <br />
        Server side code (cbo choice) =
        <asp:Label ID="lblChoice" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="file cbo"
            OnClientClick="fillcbo();return false"
            CssClass="btn"
            />
        <br />

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
            width="200px" onchange="mysel(this);">

        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="cboChoice" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <br />

    </div>
    <script>

        function fillcbo() {
            var cbo = $('#DropDownList1')
            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = i;
                option.innerHTML = 'item ' + i;
                cbo.append(option);
            }
        }

        function mysel(cbo) {
            $('#cboChoice').val(cbo.value)
        }
    </script>
```

And code behind for the post-back button is this:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Debug.Print($"combo choice = {cboChoice.Value}")
    lblChoice.Text = cboChoice.Value

End Sub
```

thus, when we run, we get this:

[image]